# display PNG from http get request

Tags: javascript, angular, http

i'm working with angular 4, I'm using an api that return an image with **content-type : img/png**

The http method :

```
return this.http.get('URL', this.options)
    .map((res: Response) => res.text());
// can be also : res.arrayBuffer() // res.blob()
```

The http get response (in text and in ARC ) is like that :

```
�PNG  IHDR��"͹�W�W��zؽ�|+q%�   ��Y������M缥{��U��H�ݏ)L�L�~�6/'6Q׌�}���:��l'���� �R�L�&�~Lw?�
```

I tried different methods to convert it and display it :

- getting response as **blob** and convert it using :

  ```
   new Uint8Array(response)
  ```
- Getting the image as **arrayBuffer** and then convert it using :

  ```
    arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) {
    let binary = '';
    let bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    let len = bytes.byteLength;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
    }
    return window.btoa(binary);
   }
  ```

Both of them didnt worked for me and the image is not displaying.

My question so is , what is the real format of the response (blob, arraybuffer or text ) and how to display it ?

Comment: Why don't you simply use it as the image url in a `img` tag ?

Comment: this is what i'm trying to do , but it dont appear ! its not showing wen i use  it ! Actually i need to convert the response to and url ! and this is what i'm trying to do !

Comment: Use `<img>` **instead of** `this.http.get()`, not as well as.

Comment: But why do you want to convert the response of an... URL to an... URL? You already have the URL from your API so just put in the `src` attribute!

Comment: `this.http!.get` is to get the image from the server ! how can i use `<img>` instead ??

Comment: @belhadjhaythem - `<img src="url goes here">`

Comment: THE console response : `GET unsafe: that url` 
This is because the response that i already told you in the question its not an URL that i put it simply to `src` tag !!

Comment: `ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`

Comment: @belhadjhaythem — You are putting a URL into `this.http.get` and getting a response out. We told you to put the **URL** into the `src` attribute. Do not put the response into the `src` attribute.

Comment: how can i log to console the total url with the params ? eg: `http://test.com?param1=&param2=..`

Comment: @belhadjhaythem Did you try the code I mentioned in the below given answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can achieve this using the `fetch` API.

Let's first return the response as a `blob`.
And then you can use `URL.createObjectURL()` to create an file object.

```
fetch(URL)
  .then(res=>{return res.blob()})
  .then(blob=>{
    var img = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    // Do whatever with the img
    document.getElementById('img').setAttribute('src', img);
  })
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/77q9mh34/2/)

Comment: `.then(res=>{return response.blob()})` has to be corrected to use the same var name ^^, and `setAttribute('src', obj)` shouldn't this be `setAttribute('src', img)`